# TabLayout: Lag when switching fragments

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, lag

I have 50 fragments with at least 20 components in each one.
I'm experiencing a delay (lag) when switching tabs, even though I've used this statement:

```
viewpager.setOfscreenPageLimit(2)
```

but it didn't work.
I tried to initialize the tablayout with the fragments in a different thread (apart from the UI thread), like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

                        // Add Fragments  
                        // Here there are 50 fragments, but I added just 2 
                        //fragments for simplicity

                        //region Phase Five
                        adapter.addFragment(new PhaseFiveTestTwoFragment(), "");

                        adapter.addFragment(new LessonOneFragment(), "");
                        //endregion

                        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

                        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

                    }
                }, 100);
```

But, I still had a lag when switching tabs.

This is an example of how many components I have:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use [method tracing](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler#method_traces) and determine exactly where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Handler for this one. You really don't need to set up a delay for this

Use this as your ViewPagerAdapter (Which is just a standard ViewPager Adapter Structure):

```js
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  private final List < Fragment > mFragList = new ArrayList < > ();



  public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragList.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return mFragList.size();
  }

  public void addFragmentI(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragList.add(fragment);
  }
  private void removeFragmentI(Collection < Fragment > fragment) {
    mFragList.removeAll(fragment);
  }
}
```

And for setting Adapter Use something like This:

```js
Fragment[] frags = {
  new Fragment1(),
  new Fragment2(),
  new Fragment3(),
  new Fragment4(),
  new Fragment5()
};
for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
  pagerAdapter.addFragmentI(frags[i]);
}
mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
mTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

This must work without a glitch. Keep your Fragments Light as well

Comment: i implemented your solution first place but it didn't work.

Comment: alright, so be sure that the problem is in your Layout. For example what are you using for Gradient in the item Background?

Comment: cause the Textviews are fine however you use them. can u upload your item xml?